# How to integrate CLEditor to comment system?

Tags: plugin-development, comments, wysiwyg

I would like to improve the comment editing for user by adding a simple WYSIWYG editor, and I selected [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) as possible good candidate because it is light, customizable and jQuery based.

I searched if it already exists a plugin that implement it but I was not able to found any. So I decided to write my own plugin.

Do you have any suggestions about which Wordpress actions or filters should I look to start?

Answer (score 1):

In modern WP all of comment form is produced by extensively hook-able [`comment_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) function. Also see [WordPress Theme Tip: The Comment Form tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-theme-tip-the-comment-form/).

Other than that you will likely need to [enqueue scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).